# Is it possible to access a variable declared in typescript into javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using bootstrap and I have a file 'global.ts' in my 'src/app' containing a variable 'server_url' which is used in my whole application.

There is a way to access the value of this variable inside a plugin js file located in a folder 'src/assets/plugin/js'?

I found a lot of suggestions about the opposite i.e. accessing a variable declared inside a js file from a ts file, but I can't really find information about this.

Comment: no because js doesnt know anything about typescript - you would need to compile it to access the variable

Comment: A quick and dirty trick is to simply write it to the `window` global object. As long as your JS script attempts to assess the variable *after* it is declared.

Comment: I was suspecting this was the fact... Thank you! If you wish, convert it to an answer, i think it would be interesting for people passing by. good idea the global var, i think i'll do this way